streamlit not working (show blank page) on microsoft edge and safari brower
I just created a simple Streamlit app using the three lines of code below:
st.header('test browser')
st.write('st write is okay')
st.button('test button')

My Streamlit environment server configuration is Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.11, Streamlit 1.38. It works well on Chrome and Firefox, 360, QQ browser, etc. But on MacBook Pro Safari and Windows Microsoft Edge, the page is blank. When I checked the console of the Microsoft Edge browser, it showed an error message: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number, main.33cac65c.js.

It seems something is wrong with the main JavaScript compatibility. On Safari, I didn't know how to check the console, so I did not get the error message. What should I do? Are there some ways to solve this problem?
I tried python 3.7 and Streamlit 1.23.1 on my MacBook locally, it seems safari works well.

I test different streamlit version. The results is that: for version <= 1.32.0, the page works okay on safari browser (15.6.1), if it is version>=1.33, the page is blank. And at the same time, Microsoft Edge 42.17134 always showed blank page

Welcome to the biggest pain in the world, the users being allowed to pick their own browsers.  That means you get to write a website, then browse it in every possible browser to find the issues, and make special code to detect if its that browser and display the alternate code instead.  Each browser has its own terms and features that have to be invoked to accomplish certain things.
